# Why does Terraform not hash sensitive values?

Tags: terraform

As I understand it, Terraform only keeps all values (no matter if they are marked as sensitive or not) in clear text in the state file for comparison purposes.

So I was wondering why they don't just hash the values? Modern hashing algorithms are quite fast and changes to the initial value would also clearly lead to changes in the hashed values.

I assume there must be more to it as not storing sensitive values in clear text is probably one of the first things you ever learn in IT, but I couldn't find it out.

Comment: Well, if you are storing the state locally, then I would argue it's a bigger issue than not having hashed values. There are different ways of performing what you mention, for example, [Sops](https://github.com/getsops/sops) or something similar. Additionally, if you're using S3 as a remote backend you can also encrypt the state file so that not only sensitive data is not readable but rather the entire state file if you don't have the permissions to decrypt. I do however agree that it would be great to have that natively in terraform. :)

Comment: Thanks for the advice, we are using an encrypted blob storage with double encryption (infra structure level + file level). However, the issue remains: I don't want to have secrets in the state file which are eventually stored in a vault.

Btw.: To prevent it, I use terraform_data with local-exec and a randomly generated value whereever possible.

However, this is not about how to live with it or prevent it but just why they even do it :)

Comment: No one here is going to be able to answer this question. We dont know why Hashicorp chose that route. However like @MarkoE says, use a remote backend that has encryption at rest and uses https, Then terraform will only hold the data in memory when running and then update the remote backend. That way all data between terraform and the remote backend will be encrypted as well as the data at rest on the remote backend being encrypted. https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/state/sensitive-data

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a ongoing topic of debate since at least 2016, [this is a good starting point to deep dive](https://github.com/opentofu/opentofu/issues/874).

OpenTofu is a Terraform fork, it tries to address this issue.
[Here](https://github.com/opentofu/opentofu/issues/874) is the thread for it.

An approach to further minimize the risk, is to use secret rotation if your other application/components support it. "Only" (yeah i know) the initial secret will be stored. But this is still not ideal.

Reversibility: Hashing is a one-way process, meaning you can't reverse the process to retrieve the original value. This poses a problem when Terraform needs to use the value from the state file during plan and apply operations. It wouldn't be able to retrieve and use the original value if it's hashed. But yes for sensitive data there are scenarios where it could be used as you mentioned, to identify changes.